# Inject Service into MVC View with Unity.Mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I've just started working with Unity Dependency Injection. I've figured out how to use it with Controllers, and with Models. However I'm not sure how to use it with Views...

What I want to do, is be able to retrieve lookup lists from within the View using a registered Service.

Looking at this URL http://blog.simontimms.com/2015/06/09/getting-lookup-data-into-you-view/ it shows how to do it with MVC6. It uses the @inject directive in the view. However I'm stuck with MVC5, which doesn't appear to have this directive.

Is there some MVC5 alternative to @inject?

I'm registering my services and repositories like so...

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterComponents()
    Dim container = New UnityContainer()

    container.RegisterType(Of IMyService, MyService)()
    container.RegisterType(Of IRepository(Of MyModel), MyRepository)()

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(New UnityDependencyResolver(container))
End Sub
```

I access the services in my controllers like this...

```
<Dependency>
Public Property MyModelService() As IMyService
```

All I need to know now is how to inject the services into my razor views.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I don't think there is a way to do that. However, there should be no need, regardless. Views should have as a little code as possible. It's a violation of the MVC pattern to do work like interacting with some service within a view. Instead, handle that in your controller and pass the relevant data into your view.

Comment: Also, I wasn't previously aware about the @inject directive. Sweet God, that's going to lead to some awful code. Never understood why Microsoft always adds landmines like that to their stuff. Sheesh.

Comment: My reasoning was to try to avoid cluttering up my controller with the code to populate lists etc. Which are only relevant to the view. The article I linked to explains it well. I do see your point though.

Comment: The thing is that that work is the job of the controller, not the view. It's not "cluttering" when it's necessary work that needs to be done.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That seems to be a fairly debatable topic. Populating and validating a model is certainly the job of the controller, but populating drop down lists of options isn't a natural fit for a controller. These lists have no inherent meaning outside of the view, and a controller needn't even know they exist. I agree the view should have as little code as possible. The actual job of retrieving the lists would be the job of the service and repository layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a relatively neat solution.

I just create my own view base class to inherit from WebViewPage (generic, and non-generic), and then put the injected service properties in there.

```
Namespace MyNamespace
    Public MustInherit Class MyWebViewPage
        Inherits MyWebViewPage(Of Object)

    End Class

    Public MustInherit Class MyWebViewPage(Of T)
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage(Of T)

        <Dependency>
        Public Property MyModelService() As MyNamespace.IMyModelService

    End Class

End Namespace
```

I then add this to the Views/Web.config, like so...

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyNamespace.MyWebViewPage"/>
```

All of the service properties and methods are then automatically available to all my views.

Comment: Is this a mvc or a webforms solution? I don't understand where to put this.

Comment: @WoIIe This is MVC. The class goes wherever you want to put it. Be aware, this example is VB.net.

Comment: One year later, I understood it :D

Answer (score 2):

This should probably have limited usage, but I have run into spots where it is handy.

C# Version using Unity

```
public class InjectedWebViewPage : InjectedWebViewPage<object>
{
}

public class InjectedWebViewPage<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    [Dependency] protected ISomeService SomeService { get; set; }
    /*
     * Other Services here...
     */

    public override void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

Put the new class anywhere, just reference it in the Views/web.config as @user1751825 states

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyNamespace.InjectedWebViewPage"/>
```